# Safe residential use of high power switching DC power supplies

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm looking to power a high power stereo amplifier using a 24V 17A switching power supply or, in another case, using a 48V 7.3A power supply. These are not your typical encased bricks, but rather come in metal cases, with active cooling, and -- the issue -- very exposed terminals for AC in and DC out. (One supply is coming from Mean Well, the other from Chengliang via Amazon.)

The question I have is this: What is the right (and to code, if applicable) way to ensure the *safe* home use of power supplies of this sort?

I take full responsibility for what I do in my own home, and will use a licensed electrician if needed.

Thanks for your advice/insight.

Kevin

Comment: Buy from a dealer who is reputable in selling power supplies of a quality nature that are backed by full manufacturing traceability and data sheets / manuals. Does that should like Shamazon to you?

Answer (score 6):

If you're referring to this style of power supply:

[image]

These power supplies are supposed to be mounted in an enclosure. First, to keep fingers away from the contacts, but also because the wire terminals are not designed to handle any kind of wire movement. There is no place to mount a power cord with a strain relief.

If you don't want to build an enclosure, then you can't use one of these and leave it on the floor in your living room. You must use a brick instead.

First check the manual to see if it needs a main filter or fuse (usually they are already integrated). Then check if it is Class 1 (needs Earth) or Class 2 (does not need Earth). Even if the power supply is Class 2, if you use a metal enclosure for your project, it is absolutely recommended to earth it.

I'd recommend an IEC inlet on your enclosure, for convenience. Then [proper earthing of the chassis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422550/proper-chassis-grounding), and a power switch that is rated for the inrush current of the power supply. Crimp ferrules on your wires make a more reliable connection to the screw terminals.

If you use a plastic enclosure, then you don't have to earth it, but you still need an earth connection for the power supply if it is class 1.

Besides that, the enclosure should have good ventilation to get rid of the heat.

Note a bridged class D amp can output a peak voltage almost equal to its power supply voltage. So with 24V the maximum "RMS" power in a 4 ohm speaker will be 24^2/4/R=72W, and with 48V it will be 288W. So I don't know what you'll do with the 24V supply exactly, unless you have lots of speakers in parallel...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to "OEM" power supplies.  These are intended to be mounted inside the equipment they power, so the input and output terminals will not be accessible to the end user of the equipment.

It is up to you to install them in a manner that will protect the terminals from accidental contact.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Yes, OEM power supplies. Thanks for pushing me along in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

For use in the USA, electrical codes generally require products that are "hard wired" rather than plugged in to be "acceptable to the authority having jurisdiction." To be acceptable, products generally must have the label of independent testing laboratory such as UL or ETL. The label must pertain to the complete product as sold with no alterations. The product must be used as intended. If something is intended to be inside an enclosure, that makes it a different product that must be evaluated by a testing laboratory and labelled.

Plug-in products are generally not covered by electrical codes, but sellers are strongly urged to sell and consumers are strongly urged to buy only products that are labelled. There are often public service announcements on TV about that during the Christmas shopping season.

A power supply that is marked like the one in the answer by @bobflux can be mounted inside an enclosure by an authorized builder and labeled with a laboratory label. That is too expensive for most people, so they enclose it themselves and take whatever risk is involved.

Comment: C. Cowie, Thanks. I will build it only to use myself, but I want to do it safely. I've got a working prototype. In terms of current, I don't know how to get 17A into a device over its 5.5mm X 2.1mm standard DC plug. The one that I took apart didn't appear to be made for that kind of current. Even the AC adapter I had for 120-AC-into-project-box says it's rated only for 10A, Where can one source parts meeting these kind of more demanding (e.g., higher current) specs?

Comment: I would look at sources that supply electrical components for recreational vehicle, truck and marine use.

Comment: Having thought more, what I think I'm confronting is inadequacy in the amplifier design to sustain the highest input power that the chip in theory can tolerate. I now see it's hopeless to expect to get that sort of power in over a 5.5mm x 2.1mm barrel plug, for example. Although the chip and marketing agree on maximum 48v, up to ~7.5A, the device power-in plug isn't up to it. I'm waiting to hear back  the manufacturer's recommendations: https://www.aiyima.com/products/amplifier-aiyima-a07-tpa3255-2-0-channel-300wx2-hifi?variant=32922293272651